# Differences between soft knee and hard knee in Dynamic Range Compression (DRC)?

Tags: dynamic-range-compression

I want to know more about where it is advantageous to use a soft knee and where and why a hard knee is preferred. Also I would like to get my hands on some good resources which talk about implementation of soft knee in DRC

Comment: we need to be careful with the "compression" tag.  most DSPers think of data compression, but this is signal level compression.

Comment: hey thanks @endolith for creating the tag and applying it to a few different posts.

Comment: now someone needs to rename "compression" to "data-compression".  I'm not allowed apparently

Comment: well you got more rep than me, so i can't either.

Comment: May I suggest a tag for `companding` (or compansion) which results from a merger of compressing and expanding? @robert bristow-johnson

Answer (score 7):

Regarding advantages - there is only one I can think of... The soft knee makes the compressor less noticeable. It sounds more natural, especially when you are dealing with higher compression ratios (like 4:1, etc.).

On the other hand, if you want to participate in the "Loudness War", then you should rather use hard knee, as it allows you to squeeze out even more loudness.

---

Regarding implementation. Assuming the:

$T$ - threshold

$W$ - soft knee width (soft knee extends from $T-\frac{W}{2}$ up to $T+\frac{W}{2}$)

$R$ - compression ratio

The soft knee compressor is governed by the equation:

$$
y_G = \begin{cases}
x_G & x_G-T<\frac{-W}{2} \\
x_G+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{R}-1\right)\left( x_G - T+ \frac{W}{2}\right)^2}{2W} & |x_G-T| \le \frac{W}{2} \\
T+\frac{x_G-T}{R} & x_G - T > \frac{W}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Here is how the compression curve will look like:

[image]

If you want to achieve the hard knee, then just drop the middle equation:

$$
y_G = \begin{cases}
x_G & x_G < T \\
T+\frac{x_G-T}{R} & x_G > T
\end{cases}
$$

Obviously then you will get the following compression characteristic:

[image]

---

Whenever you have to do something about Dynamic Range Compression, I suggest you to take a look at the article below. Those guys did a great job of putting together all the info. Nonetheless I highly recommend reading the articles in references.

> [Giannoulis D. et al. - **Digital Dynamic Range Compressor Design - A
> Tutorial and
> Analysis**](https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/%7Ejosh/documents/2012/GiannoulisMassbergReiss-dynamicrangecompression-JAES2012.pdf)

Comment: I'm curious to know how that soft knee formula is derived. The tutorial doesn't mention anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

depends on if you like discontinuities in your signal or parameter processing chain, or if you like it if the mathematics is as continuous as possible.

how to implement a soft knee?  consider this function:

$$ f(x) \ = \ \alpha_0 \ x \ - \ \beta \ \log_2 \left(1 + 2^{\frac{\alpha_0 - \alpha_1}{\beta} (x - x_0)} \right) $$

for $ 0 < \alpha_1 < \alpha_0 $ and $ \beta > 0 $.

tell me what you get for tiny $\beta$ and then what you get for nominal $\beta$.